# How to find and groupby different values and get count in mongoDb?

Tags: mongodb, group-by

Below is my schema.. I need to get the count of my'file_id'(i will define my file_id) with different 'user_email'.. note ..not the count of file_id with similar and different user_email i need only the count of my file_id with different user_email.any help?

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("591bedc8c942a3514ed09b24"),

    "file_id" : "58450c20b053dc426b935927",
    "description" : "get your output ready",
    "user_email" : "abc@gmail.com",
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("591bedc8c942a3514ed09b25"),

    "description" : "get your output ready",
    "user_email" : "abc@gmail.com",
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("591bedc8c942a3514ed09b26"),

    "file_id" : "58450c20b053dc426b935927",
    "description" : "get your output ready",
    "user_email" : "hgi@gmail.com",
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("591bedc8c942a3514ed09b27"),

    "file_id" : "58450c20b053dc426b935927",
    "description" : "get your output ready",
    "user_email" : "rfd@gmail.com",
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("591beea4a62559b4506549e0"),

    "file_id" : "58450c20b053dc426b935927",
    "description" : "get your output ready",
    "user_email" : "negan@gmail.com",
    "__v" : 0
}



db.myschema.aggregate({$group:{"file_id":"58450c20b053dc426b935927","user_email" : "abc@gmail.com",count: { $sum: 1 }} })
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me

Comment: i need to get the count of  file ids  which i am defining with my query with different user email..if there is ten records with same file_id and same user_email i need the count as 1 and not as 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following query should give you the unique count of `file_id` and `user_email`

```
db.myschema.aggregate([

{
  $group: {
    _id: {"file_id": "$file_id", "user_email": "$user_email"},
    count: {$sum: 1}
  }
},
{

    $project: {
    _id: 0,
    "user_email": "$_id.user_email",
    "file_id": "$_id.file_id",
    "count": 1
    }

}

]);
```

**EDIT**
So, if you are interested in particular `file_id` only then you can simply filter the result as follows:

```
let fileId = '58450c20b053dc426b935927';

db.myschema.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { file_id: "$file_id", user_email: "$user_email" },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "_id.file_id": fileId
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      user_email: "$_id.user_email",
      file_id: "$_id.file_id",
      count: 1
    }
  }
]);
```

Comment: ya this query gives me the unique count of every different records like this..
{ "count" : 12, "user_email" : "123@gmail.com", "file_id" : "58450c20b053dc426b935927" }
{ "count" : 1, "user_email" : "234@gmail.com", "file_id" : "5841509cbe1c099108a887f4" }
{ "count" : 2, "user_email" : "456@gmail.com", "file_id" : "5841509cbe1c099108a887f4" }
{ "count" : 1, "user_email" : "678@gmail.com", "file_id" : "5841509cbe1c099108a887f4" }
....
but in this record i need to search for a particular file_id with the query how can i do that?

Comment: @Jagadeesh please see the update. Yes! you can filter out desired result by adding the match aggregation pipeline.